# Can't SSH using OpenSSH: Connection Timeout

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, openssh, ssh-keys

I'm struggeling to get ssh work on Windows 10. It works fine on my company's laptop, but I can't access it right now and I need to ssh with my private computer.

On my work computer, I use the Git Bash terminal, have my keys in .ssh together with the config file. Then I simply type `ssh machinename` and I'm directly logged in the remote machine as the ssh-key is included in the machine's `authorized_keys`.

On my private computer, I use the same ssh-key and the same config (also in .ssh). However, when trying to ssh in the same manner using the Git Bash terminal on my private computer, I get `ssh: connect to host machinename port 22: Connection timed out`. I already made sure to add the SSH keys to the ssh-agent: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-SSH-key-to-the-ssh-agent
And followed the tips [here](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html#installing-ssh-keys), to remove the environmental variable set by TortoiseGit (which I also have installed on my work laptop, btw).

Weirdly, I can still log in to some remote machines using Putty and typing my password. However, I'm annoyed by having to type my password and I want to log-in using my ssh key. Also, some machines cannot be accessed with Putty nor Git bash... What's the problem?

Comment: It's possible that your home IP is being blocked for some reason. I would suggest installing [`wireshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/) on both machines and comparing the dialogues in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your tip: If I use a VPN to my work network, I can ssh via Git Bash without problem! The weird thing is that I can still use Putty + Password with some machines - even without VPN. How is that possible if my home IP is blocked?

Comment: Could it be using a different port, which `putty` is finding, but not `ssh`? A `wireshark` trace would tell you this. Or, more simply, a port monitor such as `netstat -a -n -o` will tell which remote port is open when the connection is established.

Comment: You're right. Putty uses port 10022 instead of 20. If I adjust this in my config, I can also access these remote machines using Git Bash and without VPN. For the remaining machines, I guess, I'll have to reconfigure the remote machines or keep using my VPN to access them. Thank you!

Comment: In passing, I came across this [interesting link](https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2012/03/12/why-putting-ssh-on-another-port-than-22-is-bad-idea/): while I don't necessarily agree with the conclusion, the discussion raises many security issues which are good to know about and can explain otherwise inexplicable `ssh` connect failures.